# How to add items to the following lists?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a following list and I want to add new items to that list when I click a button. How to achieve it?

```
List<dynamic> list = [
    {
      'id': 0,
      'leading': 'Payment Application',
      'trailing': 'System',
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'leading': 'Reference Number',
      'trailing': 'SYM12113OI',
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'leading': 'Total',
      'trailing': '\$15.00',
    },
    {
      'id': 3,
      'leading': 'Details',
      'trailing': 'Civil Employment',
    },
  ];
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTing won't get you an answer any faster. It's also rather rude to SHOUT at people you're asking for *free help* to solve **your problem**.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
TextButton(
  child: Text("child"),
  onPressed: () {
    list.add(value);
  }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

1st create a Model for Your List Object :
Example:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final listModel = listModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<ListModel> listModelFromJson(String str) => List<ListModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => ListModel.fromJson(x)));

String listModelToJson(List<ListModel> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class ListModel {
    ListModel({
        this.id,
        this.leading,
        this.trailing,
    });

    int id;
    String leading;
    String trailing;

    factory ListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ListModel(
        id: json["id"],
        leading: json["leading"],
        trailing: json["trailing"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "leading": leading,
        "trailing": trailing,
    };
}
```

---

Now You can define your List Like this:

```
List<ListModel> _list = [];
```

For Add Data In your List you can do :

```
_list.add(ListModel(id:1022,leading:"leading name",trailing:"training part "));
```